# shipping label not generate in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2

I want to generate the shipping label in Magento 2 but am unable to generate the shipping label. every time I got this error.
Does anyone know about this please help

**There are no shipping labels related to selected orders**

Comment: which shipping method are you using and also do you have tracking number added ?

Comment: i am using flate rate shipping method

Comment: have you created shipment too ?

Comment: yes i have created

Comment: could you send me its screen shot ?

Answer (score 0):

**There are no shipping labels related to selected orders** is error when you have not created shipment and / or have not added tracking number for the orders.

In order to get it work, you need to create shipment and add tracking for that order.

like in attached there is one New / Open order and have not created shipment for it.
[image: No shipping screen]

Comment: i flow every step already but not working